# How to access specific value from deep within Json output in C# console application

Tags: c#, json, nested

I am accessing the following Json output from a sports statistics API and want to get the specific value that rests in the away team ID for each game being played. (dates>games>teams>away>team:id).  Json show here: https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/schedule

I've been successful using jObject.Parse() for much of the rest of my project but this value is buried and my knowledge is limited on how to expand my nest to reach it.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

so far I am trying like so but getting errors stating I am accessing invalid key values.

```
     public List<string> GetAwayTeamsPlayingToday()
    {
        var URL = new UriBuilder("https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/schedule");

        var client = new WebClient();

        List<string> awayTeamsPlayingToday = new List<string>();

        JObject ScheduleData = JObject.Parse(client.DownloadString(URL.ToString()));

        string lplayerAwayTeamId = string.Empty;

        var dates = ScheduleData["dates"] as JArray;
        foreach (JObject date in dates)
        {
            var games = dates["games"] as JArray;
            foreach (JObject game in games)
            {
                var teams = games["teams"] as JArray;
                foreach (JObject team in teams)
                {
                    var away = teams["away"] as JArray;
                    foreach (JObject tm in away)
                    {
                        var awayTeam = away["team"] as JObject;

                        lplayerAwayTeamId = awayTeam["id"].ToString();

                        awayTeamsPlayingToday.Add(lplayerAwayTeamId);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return awayTeamsPlayingToday;
    }
```

Comment: You may look at [querying with JsonPath](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this

```
var URL = new UriBuilder("https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/schedule");

var client = new WebClient();

List<string> awayTeamsPlayingToday = new List<string>();

JObject ScheduleData = JObject.Parse(client.DownloadString(URL.ToString()));

var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(ScheduleData.ToString());

//this sample is for first date, first game
var awayTeamId = data.dates[0].games[0].teams.away.team.id;

//to get each game
foreach (var date in data.dates)
{
    foreach (var game in date.games)
    {
        var id = game.teams.away.team.id;            
        //your logic
    }
}
```

Comment: This works fantastically for the first result, thank you so much!  any idea how I can loop through each "games" so I can generate a list of all away teams playing in the json?